# LuaJIT & FFI: How to use char* properly?

Tags: lua

I have looked at the LuaJIT tutorial at: http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_tutorial.html

I am trying to get more into Lua and wanted to see how easy it would be for me to call a simple "lowercase" function in a "libutility.so" I have written in C.

So here is the C function I want to call:

```
void lowercase(char* str){    
    int z;    
    for (z = 0; str[z]; z++){    
      str[z] = tolower(str[ z ]);    
    }    
}
```

So now I want to call this function from Lua...here is my code using LuaJIT's FFI

```
local ffi = require("ffi")
ffi.cdef[[
void lowercase(char* str);
]]
local utility = ffi.load("utility")    
local buf = ffi.new("char[?]", 11)
ffi.copy(buf, "HELLO WORLD")    
utility.lowercase(buf)
print("Result: ", #str)
```

The above code does not work...well I think it works until the LAST line of code above.

Can someone please give me some advise on how I can call this "lowercase" function and print out the result properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
local ffi = require("ffi")
ffi.cdef[[
void lowercase(char* str);
]]
local utility = ffi.load("utility")    
local buf = ffi.new("char[?]", "HELLO WORLD")
utility.lowercase(buf)
print("Result: ", ffi.string(buf))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not at all sure what `str` is, but `tolower` returns it's value in place, so you really want to be printing `buf`.